# How to merge two datasets in SAS

Tags: sas

If have two datasets that I am trying to merge:

dataset1

| sta | year | month | day | time | depth | param | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 1 | 29 | 1111 | 0.52 | 1114 | 0.39024 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 2 | 21 | 1114 | 0.52 | 1114 | 0.27746 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 3 | 19 | 1113 | 0.41 | 1114 | 0.45664 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 4 | 16 | 1125 | 0.45 | 1114 | 0.39494 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 5 | 30 | 0950 | 0.50 | 1114 | 0.57242 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 6 | 25 | 1120 | 0.51 | 1114 | 0.43937 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 7 | 30 | 1052 | 0.50 | 1114 | 0.44714 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 8 | 27 | 1017 | 0.50 | 1114 | 0.38892 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 9 | 26 | 0955 | 0.51 | 1114 | 0.4542 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 10 | 30 | 1231 | 0.35 | 1114 | 0.56264 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 11 | 26 | 1015 | 0.40 | 1114 | 0.64268 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 12 | 17 | 0956 | 0.45 | 1114 | 0.46867 |

dataset2

| sta | year | month | day | time | depth | hardness |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 1 | 29 | 1111 | 0.52 | 65.1474701 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 2 | 21 | 1114 | 0.52 | 48.5845079 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 3 | 19 | 1113 | 0.41 | 58.6831256 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 4 | 16 | 1125 | 0.45 | 52.0918074 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 5 | 30 | 950 | 0.5 | 50.0315417 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 6 | 25 | 1120 | 0.51 | . |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 7 | 30 | 1052 | 0.5 | . |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 8 | 27 | 1017 | 0.5 | . |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 9 | 26 | 955 | 0.51 | . |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 10 | 30 | 1231 | 0.35 | 35.0111982 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 11 | 26 | 1015 | 0.4 | 37.230617 |
| Sta001 | 2018 | 12 | 17 | 956 | 0.45 | 68.675662 |

When I merge them using:

```
by sta year month day time;
```

I get 12 matches

However, when I merge them using:

```
by sta year month day time depth;
```

I only get 10 matches (the records for March and October do not merge)

It might be something really obvious, but I am stumped.

Comment: I'm getting 12 records when merging them doing an inner-join in both cases.

Comment: Why would you include DEPTH as one of the BY variables?  What type of variable is DEPTH?  Is it numeric or character?  How many bytes is it using in both datasets?  If they are numeric make sure they are storing all 8 bytes of the values. What level of precision is it collected to?  Hundredths? Thousandths?  ROUND() the value before merging them.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look; depth is numeric; they are both formatted as format 5.2

Comment: I just merged the two datasets without the depth and calculated the difference between the two. If you go out to enough decimal places, there does appear to be a difference (0.0000000000000000555), so looks like I'll need to round prior to merging.

It's odd though, since the depth value assigned to each record actually has the same origin. I'll have to investigate further.

Thanks again for pointing me towards the problem and solution!

Comment: Remember the FORMAT is just the logic used to DISPLAY the value.  It has next to nothing to do with what values are stored.

Comment: Sorry - yes . . . they are both numeric and 8 bytes

Comment: You can preprocess both data sets and use `ROUND(depth,0.01)` to get their underlying representations (IEEE 754 binary floating-point format) to be the same.  Then the `MERGE` will match them.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help!